# How to extract image of bebop camera to my computer

Tags: ros, drone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to processing images obtained of bebop 1 camera from my computer, but I can not access the images. Can you help me ?
I'm using the autonomy_bebop driver but the documentation does not show me how to get images and then process them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259529/how-to-extract-image-of-bebop-camera-to-my-computer/) by [VinicioSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/30071/viniciosp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After running the bebop driver you should get an `image_raw` topic (use `rostopic list`). You can also verify the camera feed with the GUI tool `rqt_image_view`. If you see the image feed, then you can process the image data in your program like any other image topic. See [image_transport tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1